# Yii2 SESSION Nesting level too deep

Tags: php, session, yii2

A visitor chooses to buy a package;

The datails from that package are saved within the SESSION

`Yii::$app()->session['CART'] = array( 1=>2 );`

When the user tryes to pay for it, the system needs data regarding the user, like the user ID, so the user gets redrected to login.

This is where I get the error:

```
PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException

Nesting level too deep - recursive dependency?
```

How do i login the user and not loose the data stored?

Comment: Do you have the stacktrace generated by that error?

Comment: Read the following page. This may help
http://stuff.cebe.cc/yii2docs/yii-web-session.html